# can amazon web services bill a consumer (not a developer) without knowing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I have an amazon prime account and got a $1 charge from AWS. I have been looking at the site and the info seems confusing to me, it seems to be talking about developers. I don't remember signing up for AWS. I am getting a new credit card, it could just be that someone stole my old card info.

is AWS pay as you go with consumers to?
can amazon web services bill a consumer (not a developer) without knowing?

Comment: As far i know if you register a new credit card at amazon (doesn't matter if it is store, aws, prime or twitch), amazon will lock $1 to validate the card is valid. I am not sure if the amount is confirmed and charged or released.

Comment: Contact [Amazon support](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html) - they should be able to tell you what the charge is for.  AWS is not going to randomly bill you for something you haven't used.